# Wrong result when subtracting a negative number (therefore performing an addition actually) in Verilog

Tags: binary, verilog, fpga, twos-complement, fixed-point

I'm learning Verilog and, to do so, I have been told to implement a fixed-point, signed number calculator, for operations +,-,* and /. The format I have chosen for these numbers is SQ4.4; in other words, 4 bits for the integer part and 4 for the decimal one.

I'm testing the subtraction, and I have noticed that it doesn't work when I try to subtract -2 from 0 (in other words: `0 - (-2) = 0 + 2 = 2`)

Here is the code:

```
`define SUM 2'b00
`define SUB 2'b01
`define MUL 2'b10
module calc(
  output reg [15:0] res,
  input [7:0] n1, n2,
  input [1:0] op);
  
  always @ (n1, n2, op)
    case (op)
      `SUM: res = n1 + n2;
      `SUB: res = n1 - n2;
      `MUL: res = (n1*n2) >> 8;
      default: res = 16'hffff;
    endcase
  
endmodule
```

and here the testbench (I copy the whole module, but the important part is the one that assigns `-2` to `n2`):

```
module tb();
  wire [15:0] res;
  reg [7:0] n1, n2;
  reg [1:0] op;
  
  calc c(res, n1, n2, op);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("out.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1, tb);
    
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 1;
    op = `SUM;
    #10;

    repeat (7)
      begin
        n1 = n1 + 1;
        #10;
      end
    
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 2;
    op = `SUB;
    #10;
    repeat (7)
      begin
        n1 = n1 + 1;
        #10;
      end
    
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = -2;   // <============== Here is the problem
    op = `SUB;
    #10;
    repeat (7)
      begin
        n1 = n1 + 1;
        #10;
      end
    
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = (2 << 4);
    op = `MUL;
    #10;
    repeat (7)
      begin
        n1 = n1 + (1 << 4);
        #10;
      end
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

The result I obtain for that `0 -(-2)` operation is `ff02`. I have tried to go to the `SUB` case in the `calc` module and do `res = - (-2)` directly, and it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't display the result, I use EPWave to see the different channel signals. Still, I have displayed it using `$display("res = %x", res);` just in case and I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `n1`, `n2` and `res` as `signed`:

```
module calc(
  output reg signed [15:0] res,
  input      signed [7:0] n1, n2,
  input [1:0] op);
  
  always @ (n1, n2, op)
    case (op)
      `SUM: res = n1 + n2;
      `SUB: res = n1 - n2;
      `MUL: res = (n1*n2) >> 8;
      default: res = 16'hffff;
    endcase
endmodule

module tb();
  wire signed [15:0] res;
  reg  signed [7:0] n1, n2;
  reg  [1:0] op;
  
  calc c(res, n1, n2, op);
  
  initial $monitor("op=%d n1=%0d n2=%0d  res=%d", op, $signed(n1), $signed(n2), $signed(res));
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, 6.8 *Variable declarations*.

I added the `$monitor` statement to `tb`, and I get the following output:

```
op=0 n1=0 n2=1  res=          1
op=0 n1=1 n2=1  res=          2
op=0 n1=2 n2=1  res=          3
op=0 n1=3 n2=1  res=          4
op=0 n1=4 n2=1  res=          5
op=0 n1=5 n2=1  res=          6
op=0 n1=6 n2=1  res=          7
op=0 n1=7 n2=1  res=          8
op=1 n1=0 n2=2  res=         -2
op=1 n1=1 n2=2  res=         -1
op=1 n1=2 n2=2  res=          0
op=1 n1=3 n2=2  res=          1
op=1 n1=4 n2=2  res=          2
op=1 n1=5 n2=2  res=          3
op=1 n1=6 n2=2  res=          4
op=1 n1=7 n2=2  res=          5
op=1 n1=0 n2=-2  res=          2  // SUB: 0 - (-2) = 2
op=1 n1=1 n2=-2  res=          3
op=1 n1=2 n2=-2  res=          4
op=1 n1=3 n2=-2  res=          5
op=1 n1=4 n2=-2  res=          6
op=1 n1=5 n2=-2  res=          7
op=1 n1=6 n2=-2  res=          8
op=1 n1=7 n2=-2  res=          9
op=2 n1=0 n2=32  res=          0
op=2 n1=16 n2=32  res=          2
op=2 n1=32 n2=32  res=          4
op=2 n1=48 n2=32  res=          6
op=2 n1=64 n2=32  res=          8
op=2 n1=80 n2=32  res=         10
op=2 n1=96 n2=32  res=         12
op=2 n1=112 n2=32  res=         14
```

I added the comment in the output to show 0-(-2)=2.